# Implode doesn't work from different Post

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get some id's from different loops and to implode theidès on an other page, but i get every time only the last id's from the loops.

Here the code from the first page - my Form:

```
    while($rowSCA = mysql_fetch_array($ResCSCA)) {
    $libSCA =   $rowSCA['lib_service'];
    $idSCA =   $rowSCA['id_service'];
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td class='HSCA'>".$libSCA."</td><td class='HSCA'><input type='checkbox' class='HSCA' name=\"centre[".$idSCA."]\"/></td>";  
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="SCA['.$idSCA.']" value="'.$idSCA.'"></input>';   
        }    
    ...
    while($rowSRiA = mysql_fetch_array($ResCSRiA)) {

    $libSRiA =   $rowSRiA['lib_service'];
    $idSRiA =    $rowSRiA['id_service'];


        echo "<tr class='HSRiA'>";
        echo "<td class='HSRiA'>".$libSRiA."</td><td class='HSRiA'><input type='checkbox' class='HSRiA' name=\"centre[".$idSRiA."]\"/></td>";  
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="RiA['.$idSRiA.']" value="'.$idSRiA.'"></input>'; 
        }
```

Here the code from the second page of my implode:

```
    // First implode operation
    foreach($_POST['SCA'] as $Cservices) 
        {
            @$CALLservices = array($Cservices);
        }

        $IMPCServices = implode(",", $CALLservices);

    $CNewServices = $IMPCServices;

    // Second implode operation
    foreach($_POST['RiA'] as $Cservices2) 
        {
            @$CALLservices2 = array($Cservices2);
        }

        $IMPCServices2 = implode(",", $CALLservices2);

    $CNewServices2 = $IMPCServices2;

    echo $CNewServices;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $CNewServices2;
```

I must get normaly this resultset:

```
    94,100,101,104
    93
```

But i get only

```
    104
    93
```

But my var_dump still tells me, that i get all my id's correctly:

```
    array(4) {
      [94]=>
      string(2) "94"
      [100]=>
      string(3) "100"
      [101]=>
      string(3) "101"
      [104]=>
      string(3) "104"
    }
    array(1) {
      [93]=>
      string(2) "93"
    }
```

So why the implode doesn't work correctly?

Anybody an idea?

THX in advance

Comment: You're overwritting. Try use `$CALLservices = array()`, then `$CALLservices[] = $Cservices;`.

Comment: or `$IMPCServices2 = implode(",", $_POST['RiA']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding to array in wrong way try this

```
    $CALLservices2 = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($_POST['SCA'] as $Cservices) 
    {
         $CALLservices2[$i] =  $Cservices;
         $i++;
    }
```

Now do implode

```
   $IMPCServices2 = implode(",", $CALLservices2);
```

Comment: isn't this just  `$IMPCServices2 = implode(",", $_POST['SCA']);` ?

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
foreach($_POST['SCA'] as $Cservices) 
    {
        @$CALLservices = array($Cservices);
    }
```

Each time through the loop you're overwriting the variable `$CALLservices` with an array containing just the current element of the loop. If you want to make an array of all the elements, you should do:

```
$CALLservices = array()
foreach($_POST['SCA'] as $Cservices) 
    {
        $CALLservices[] = array($Cservices);
    }
```

However, you don't need this loop at all. You can just write:

```
$CALLservices = $_POST['SCA']
```

to copy the array. And why do you even need to copy the array? You can write:

```
$IMPCServices = implode(",", $_POST['SCA']);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `foreach` loop you are not taking all the values in the array.

There are different approches, but here is a basic one:

```
foreach($_POST['SCA'] as $Cservices) {
        @$CALLservices[] = $Cservices;
}

$IMPCServices = implode(",", $CALLservices);
```

Enjoy....